# cherrypy method calling another method

Tags: cherrypy

I'm trying to break up my cherrypy web app into classes. How does a method in a cherrypy app call another method? For instance, I want App.index() to call Login.index() and Login.index() to call Menu.index():

```
class App:
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # ... some initialization ...
        # HOW TO CALL Login.index() ???

class Login:
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # login form that will post to Login.do_login()
    @cherrypy.explode
    def do_login(self):
        # validate
        # HOW TO CALL Menu.index() ???
```

If I do this (which is probably not the right way):

```
class App:
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # ... some initialization ...
        return Login().index()

class Login:
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # login form that will post to "do_login"
    @cherrypy.explode
    def do_login(self):
        # validate
```

I *do* get a Login.index() form. *But* the problem is that in the form, there's a post to do_login. On submission, cherrypy will complain that "/do_login" is not found. Note the "/". In otherwords I want a URL link to "do_login" in the webpage returned by Login.index() to go to Login.do_login() and not App.do_login().

Of course everything is fine if I go to Login().index() by going a GET:

```
class App:
    login = Login()
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # ... some initialization ...
        return "Go to <a href='login'>login</a>" # CLICK ON THE LINK

class Login:
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # login form that will post to Login.do_login()
    @cherrypy.explode
    def do_login(self):
        # validate
        # HOW TO CALL Menu.index() ???
```

I must be missing something.

Comment: SOLVED: Use "raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/login')" instead of "return Login().index()".

Comment: I'm marking this as closed. But do let me know if there's a better way than raising exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can fix that in two ways, I recommend option 1 because is the more natural way of doing HTTP:

1. Set the full url on the form `action="/login/do_login"` and use [HTTPRedirect](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/cherrypy.html?highlight=internalredirect#cherrypy.HTTPRedirect) to manage the flow, for example:

   GET -> app/ ->  NOT_AUTHORIZED -> HTTP_REDIRECT[303] -> /login/

   POST -> /login/do_login -> AUTHORIZED -> HTTP_REDIRECT[303] -> /app

   ```
   class App:    
       @cherrypy.exposed
       def index(self):
           # ... some initialization ...
           raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/login/')

   class Login:
       @cherrypy.exposed
       def index(self):
           # login form that will post to "do_login"
       @cherrypy.explode
       def do_login(self):
           # validate
   ```
2. Use [internal redirects](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/cherrypy.html?highlight=internalredirect#cherrypy.InternalRedirect).

   ```
   class App:    
       @cherrypy.exposed
       def index(self):
           # ... some initialization ...
           raise cherrypy.InternalRedirect('/login/')

   class Login:
       @cherrypy.exposed
       def index(self):
           # login form that will post to "do_login"
       @cherrypy.explode
       def do_login(self):
           # validate
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need to instantiate the class you want to call...

```
class App:
    @cherrypy.exposed
    def index(self):
        # ... some initialization ...
        LoginClassObject = Login()
        # HOW TO CALL Login.index()
        LoginClassObject.index()
```

If your class is in another python file you'll have to import the class...

```
from Path.To.Login.File import Login
```

Then just repeat for Menu.index()

Here's more on class objects...

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

EDIT:

If you want you're post to go to the correct handler just specify the class in the href...

```
return "Go to <a href='/Login/login'>login</a>" # CLICK ON THE LINK
```

Or if you want it to be as the user clicked it then you're correct in using...

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/Login/login")
```

note: Be sure not to place the HTTPRedirect in a try/catch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I know that -- see the second block of code in OP. I really need the action to be as though the user "click" on LoginClassObject.index() through a link -- see the third block of code in OP. Why? Because otherwise relative paths will go wrong. For instance suppose App has method post and Login also has method post. Then using your code (or the same as the second block in OP) a URL link in Login.index() will not call Login.post(). This is my mistake that I did not make it explicit other than comment right after the second block of code in OP -- see the comment on "/".

Comment: OP modified to include comment on relative path (after second block of code) as per comment above.